# JQuery Generate gold phone numbers from number series

Tags: jquery, html, random

I got a task at work, i need to generate some gold numbers, from a number series.
Like the series: 52xxxxxx
A gold number could be like these: 52999999, 52727272 or something like it.

I'm lost where to start, and how to actually do this, and would love some finger points in the right direction.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Regular expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you want, I suggest you to do like that:

```
var minNumber = 100000;
var maxNumber = 999999;
var prefixe = 52; // if this number is not generated ?

var phonenumber = randomNumber(minNumber, maxNumber);

function randomNumber(min,max)
{
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    return prefixe + "" + randomNumber;
}
```

You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/n8m23n8q/
Tell me if I have not understand your question correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me going, and understand how to handle this. If i may ask, why the "*(max-min+1)+min)" ? what does that do?

Comment: To have a randomized number between two numbers, you must do that:
for example for 1 and 10 :
Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);